# AWS Redshift serverless - how to get the cluster id value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, serverless

I'm following the AWS documentation about how to connect to redshift [generating user credentials][1]
But the get-cluster-credentials API requires a cluster id parameter, which i don't have for a serverless endpoint. What id should I use?

EDIT:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is the screen of a serverless endpoint dashboard. There is no cluster ID.
[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzvIs.png

Comment: See the new Guide that i referenced in my updated answer

Comment: I got the connection working perfectly, when working with Serverless, you do not require the cluster id or the user. Only the database name. See the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this Guide (a newer one) that talks about Connecting to Amazon Redshift Serverless. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-connecting.html

See this information that answers your question:

**Connecting to the serverless endpoint with the Data API**
You can also use the Amazon Redshift Data API to connect to serverless endpoint. Leave off the cluster-identifier parameter in your AWS CLI calls to route your query to serverless endpoint.

**UPDATE**

I wanted to test this to make sure that a successful connection can be made. I followed this doc to setup a Serverless instance.

[Get started with Amazon Redshift Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-getting-started.html)

I loaded sample data and now have this.

[image]

Now I attemped to connect to it using **software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.RedshiftDataClient**.

The Java V2 code:

```
 try {
            ExecuteStatementRequest statementRequest = ExecuteStatementRequest.builder()
                    .database(database)
                    .sql(sqlStatement)
                    .build();

            ExecuteStatementResponse response = redshiftDataClient.executeStatement(statementRequest);
            return response.id();

        } catch (RedshiftDataException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Notice there is no cluster id or user. Only a database name (**sample_data_dev**). The call worked perfectly.

[image]

HEre is the full code example that successfully queries data from a serverless instance using the AWS SDK for Java V2.

```
package com.example.redshiftdata;

import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.model.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.RedshiftDataClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.model.DescribeStatementRequest;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * To run this Java V2 code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class RetrieveDataServerless {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    RetrieveData <database> <sqlStatement>  \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    database - the name of the database (for example, sample_data_dev). \n" +
                "    sqlStatement - the sql statement to use. \n"  ;

        String database = "sample_data_dev"  ;  
        String sqlStatement =  "Select * from tickit.sales" ; 
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        RedshiftDataClient redshiftDataClient = RedshiftDataClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        String id =  performSQLStatement(redshiftDataClient, database, sqlStatement);
        System.out.println("The identifier of the statement is "+id);
        checkStatement(redshiftDataClient,id );
        getResults(redshiftDataClient, id);
        redshiftDataClient.close();
    }

    public static void checkStatement(RedshiftDataClient redshiftDataClient,String sqlId ) {

        try {

            DescribeStatementRequest statementRequest = DescribeStatementRequest.builder()
                    .id(sqlId)
                    .build() ;

            // Wait until the sql statement processing is finished.
            boolean finished = false;
            String status = "";
            while (!finished) {

                DescribeStatementResponse response = redshiftDataClient.describeStatement(statementRequest);
                status = response.statusAsString();
                System.out.println("..."+status);

                if (status.compareTo("FINISHED") == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            System.out.println("The statement is finished!");

        } catch (RedshiftDataException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static String performSQLStatement(RedshiftDataClient redshiftDataClient,
                                             String database,
                                             String sqlStatement) {

        try {
            ExecuteStatementRequest statementRequest = ExecuteStatementRequest.builder()
                    .database(database)
                    .sql(sqlStatement)
                    .build();

            ExecuteStatementResponse response = redshiftDataClient.executeStatement(statementRequest);
            return response.id();

        } catch (RedshiftDataException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }


    public static void getResults(RedshiftDataClient redshiftDataClient, String statementId) {

        try {

            GetStatementResultRequest resultRequest = GetStatementResultRequest.builder()
                    .id(statementId)
                    .build();

            GetStatementResultResponse response = redshiftDataClient.getStatementResult(resultRequest);

            // Iterate through the List element where each element is a List object.
            List<List<Field>> dataList = response.records();

            // Print out the records.
            for (List list: dataList) {

                for (Object myField:list) {

                    Field field = (Field) myField;
                    String value = field.stringValue();
                    if (value != null)
                        System.out.println("The value of the field is " + value);
                }
            }

        } catch (RedshiftDataException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```